# i want to fetch all the values using regex in a single regcular expression extractor in jemter

Tags: regex, jmeter

This is my input box. I want to fetch the value of this box in a single regular expression extractor.

Can any one help?

```
  <input name='plaid_response' type='hidden'  
   value='{"_id":"QPO8Jo8vdDHMepg41PBwckXm4KdK1yUdmXOwK",
   "_item":"KdDjmojBERUKx3JkDd9RuxA5EvejA4SENO4AA",
   "_user":"eJXpMzpR65FP4RYno6rzuA7OZjd9n3Hna0RYa",
   "balance":  {"available":1203.42,"current":1274.93},
    "meta":{"number":"9606","name":"Plaid Savings"},
   "numbers":{"routing":"021000021","account":"9900009606",
          "wireRouting":"021000021"},"type":"depository",
            "institution_type":"fake_institution"}'>
```

Comment: Please put in some effort to write out a clear question. Edit out typos and format the quoted code properly.

Answer (score 0):

This regex extracts the value from your input field:

```
<input.*?\s*?value='([^']*)
```

For more information see: https://regex101.com/r/jG8qP6/1